# Excel formula converted to SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL code that works great and I would like to add a calculation to it. For now, I have excel calculate the difference between the dates, but I would like to see it this done by SQL.

```
SELECT 
"CUSTOMER"."NAME"
, "CUSTOMER"."USER_1"
, "CUSTOMER"."ID"
, "CUST_ORDER_LINE"."CUST_ORDER_ID" 
, "CUST_ORDER_LINE"."MISC_REFERENCE" 
, "CUST_ORDER_LINE"."PART_ID" 
, "CUST_ORDER_LINE"."PROMISE_DATE" -- 1
, "CUST_ORDER_LINE"."UNIT_PRICE" 
, "CUSTOMER_ORDER"."CUSTOMER_ID" 
, "CUSTOMER_ORDER"."PROMISE_DATE"  -- 2
, "CUSTOMER_ORDER"."ID"  
, "SHIPPER"."SHIPPED_DATE"         -- 3
, "SHIPPER_LINE"."CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO" 
, "SHIPPER_LINE"."PACKLIST_ID" 
, "SHIPPER_LINE"."USER_SHIPPED_QTY"

, THE FOLLOWING FORMULA NEEDS TO GO HERE
=IF(IF([@[PROMISE_DATE]]="",[@[SHIPPED_DATE]]-[@[PROMISE_DATE2]], 
[@[SHIPPED_DATE]]-[@[PROMISE_DATE]])<=0,"On-Time","Late")

, CAST(("SHIPPER_LINE"."USER_SHIPPED_QTY" * "CUST_ORDER_LINE"."UNIT_PRICE") AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Total_Dollars_Shipped

FROM   
("ATL"."dbo"."CUST_ORDER_LINE" "CUST_ORDER_LINE"
            INNER JOIN "ATL"."dbo"."SHIPPER_LINE" "SHIPPER_LINE" 
ON ("CUST_ORDER_LINE"."CUST_ORDER_ID"="SHIPPER_LINE"."CUST_ORDER_ID") 
AND ("CUST_ORDER_LINE"."LINE_NO"="SHIPPER_LINE"."CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO")) 
            INNER JOIN "ATL"."dbo"."SHIPPER" "SHIPPER" 
ON "SHIPPER_LINE"."PACKLIST_ID"="SHIPPER"."PACKLIST_ID"
            INNER JOIN "ATL"."dbo"."CUSTOMER_ORDER" "CUSTOMER_ORDER" 
ON "SHIPPER"."CUST_ORDER_ID"="CUSTOMER_ORDER"."ID"
            INNER JOIN "ATL"."dbo"."CUSTOMER" "CUSTOMER"
ON "CUSTOMER_ORDER"."CUSTOMER_ID" = "CUSTOMER"."ID"

WHERE 
"SHIPPER"."SHIPPED_DATE">={ts '2015-01-01 00:00:00'} AND
"SHIPPER_LINE"."USER_SHIPPED_QTY"<>0 AND
"CUST_ORDER_LINE"."UNIT_PRICE" <> 0.00

ORDER BY "SHIPPER"."SHIPPED_DATE", "CUSTOMER_ORDER"."CUSTOMER_ID"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use the [`CASE`](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/14/sql-server-case-statementexpression-examples-and-explanation/) statement for inline conditionals in SQL Server, and use the [`DATEDIFF(part, begin, end)` function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_datediff.asp). Note that this function returns integer values only with some interesting behaviors if you are close to the datepart boundary (e.g. `DATEDIFF(DAY, '2018-08-28 23:59:59', '2018-08-29')` is 1)

Answer (score 3):

I believe something like this should do the trick:

```
CASE WHEN Shipped_Date <= COALESCE(CUST_ORDER_LINE.PROMISE_DATE, CUSTOMER_ORDER.PROMISE_DATE) Then 'On-Time' Else 'Late' END
```

[`COALESCE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) returns the first Non-Null value it encounters in the list of parameters. So here if the `CUST_ORDER_LINE.Promise_Date` is null then it will return the `Customer_Order.Promise_Date`.

Instead of subtracting them and looking for negatives, we just compare the two dates to each other.

The [`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) statement will replace your `If()` logic. The Syntax is pretty simple, so it's definitely worth learning if you are going to do more of this work.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
CASE 
   WHEN Shipped_Date <= COALESCE(CUST_ORDER_LINE.PROMISE_DATE, CUSTOMER_ORDER.PROMISE_DATE) 
      THEN "On-Time" 
      ELSE "Late" 
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really answer as you already two of those. But this is too long for a comment. You should avoid using double quotes around table and column names. And aliases are great, but just using the table name again makes the alias the same thing which kind of defeats the purpose. :) Using shorter alias this wall of text can become quite easy on the eyes. Here is an example.

```
SELECT 
    c.NAME
    , c.USER_1
    , c.ID
    , ol.CUST_ORDER_ID 
    , ol.MISC_REFERENCE 
    , ol.PART_ID 
    , ol.PROMISE_DATE -- 1
    , ol.UNIT_PRICE 
    , co.CUSTOMER_ID 
    , co.PROMISE_DATE  -- 2
    , co.ID  
    , s.SHIPPED_DATE         -- 3
    , sl.CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO 
    , sl.PACKLIST_ID 
    , sl.USER_SHIPPED_QTY

    --, THE FOLLOWING FORMULA NEEDS TO GO HERE
    --=IF(IF([@[PROMISE_DATE]]=,[@[SHIPPED_DATE]]-[@[PROMISE_DATE2]], 
    --[@[SHIPPED_DATE]]-[@[PROMISE_DATE]])<=0,On-Time,Late)

    , CAST((sl.USER_SHIPPED_QTY * ol.UNIT_PRICE) AS decimal(15, 2)) AS Total_Dollars_Shipped
FROM ATL.dbo.CUST_ORDER_LINE ol
INNER JOIN ATL.dbo.SHIPPER_LINE sl ON ol.CUST_ORDER_ID = sl.CUST_ORDER_ID 
            AND ol.LINE_NO = sl.CUST_ORDER_LINE_NO
INNER JOIN ATL.dbo.SHIPPER s ON sl.PACKLIST_ID = s.PACKLIST_ID
INNER JOIN ATL.dbo.CUSTOMER_ORDER co ON s.CUST_ORDER_ID = co.ID
INNER JOIN ATL.dbo.CUSTOMER c ON co.CUSTOMER_ID = c.ID
WHERE s.SHIPPED_DATE>={ts '2015-01-01 00:00:00'} 
    AND sl.USER_SHIPPED_QTY <> 0 
    AND ol.UNIT_PRICE <> 0.00
ORDER BY s.SHIPPED_DATE, co.CUSTOMER_ID
```